# Combine two sub queries by min value

Tags: php, mysql

My idea is to combine the two sub queries.They are almost the same- the sub queries, just that the second one has +1 WHERE condition .I want to get the both results and between them to return the MIN starttime then group it so that there must be only one row for each day of the month based on the minimum starttime.But it looks like that the syntax is not right, giving the error at 
**{SELECT B.id FROM** this place;

```
SELECT MIN(starttime) starttime,MIN(id) id FROM AG GROUP BY starttime
{
   SELECT B.id FROM
   (
       SELECT DATE(starttime) date_starttime,MIN(starttime) starttime
       FROM calendar
       WHERE starttime between '2012-02-00 00:00:00' and '2012-03-00 00:00:00'
       GROUP BY DATE(starttime)
   ) A LEFT JOIN calendar B USING (starttime), 
   SELECT D.id FROM
   (
       SELECT DATE(starttime) date_starttime,MIN(starttime) starttime
       FROM calendar
       WHERE repeat != 0 AND starttime between '2012-02-00 00:00:00' and '2012-03-00 00:00:00'
       GROUP BY DATE(starttime)
   ) AD LEFT JOIN calendar BD USING (starttime)
}
```

Comment: you have wrote wrong query, put your table structure with data

Comment: I have, table - calendar, id,starttime- which is the date, repeat- int number.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a PHP construct (the curly braces) in an MySQL context - MySQL doesn't understand curly brace brackets and so gives you an error at that point in your query.

You probably adapted this from a PHP program, I would guess? In PHP, the PHP interpreter resolves the expression inside the curly braces and substitutes it in the MySQL query before it hands the query to MySQL.